# Why onClick fires several times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm useing `Semantic-ui-react` `redux` and `react-router-dom`. In my component I have navbar:

```
<Menu >     
  <Menu.Item as={Link} to="/" onClick = {this.onNavBarItemCLick()}>
    home
  </Menu.Item>

  <Menu.Item as={Link} to="profile" onClick = {this.onNavBarItemCLick()}>
    profile
  </Menu.Item>

  <Menu.Item as={Link} to="shop" onClick = {this.onNavBarItemCLick()}>
    shop
  </Menu.Item>
</Menu>
```

If I click on the one of nav items method `onNavBarItemClick` fires 3 times. Why it happens?

Comment: Best practices and various ways to attach event handlers can be found at https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html. You could take a look to see what might suit your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

You need to replace

```
onClick = {this.onNavBarItemCLick()}
```

with

```
onClick = {() => this.onNavBarItemCLick()}  // perserving class's this
```

or if you prefer the bind notation

```
onClick = {this.onNavBarItemCLick.bind(this)} // perserving class's this
```

else

```
onClick = {this.onNavBarItemCLick} // not perserving class's this
```

**Why it happens**

It happens because when you click `render()` is called again.
React is very efficient in re-rendering, so it's what it's supposed to happen.

The issue with your implementation was that instead of passing a method reference, you were passing the returned value of such method.

Answer (score 3):

Because you call method immediately, instead you should only pas handler to onClick attribute:

```
as={Link} to="shop" onClick = {this.onNavBarItemCLick.bind(this)}>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you should not call it right away in the onClick prop. use this

`<Menu.Item as={Link} to="/" onClick = {this.onNavBarItemCLick}>`

What ends up happening, is the onNavBarItemCLick being called every time the render function is called when state changes

Answer (score 1):

The `onClick` prop takes a function as value so what's the problem here ?

```
<MyComponent onClick={this.handleClick()} />
```

using `this.handleClick()` instantly call the function and gives its return value to `onClick`. What you want here is to give the function itself to `onClick` like so

```
<MyComponent onClick={this.handleClick} />
```

But you'll probably get another error there if `this.handleClick` uses `this` as it is not automatically bound in a React class. There are ways to fix this like binding `this` in the constructor, using an array function for `handleClick` or directly bind `this` when passing the function to `onClick` like

```
<MyComponent onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} />
```

Going a bit further, you could also return a function in `handleClick` which here is totally useless. It's only to illustrate :

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  handleClick () {
    return () => { console.log('I am triggered on click') }
  }

  render () {
    // We call this.handleClick() which returns the function
    // that'll be actually called on click.
    return <div onClick={this.handleClick()} />
  }
}
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

When you do `this.onNavBarItemClick()`, what happens is that the parenthesis execute the function at that point. Whereas `this.onNavBarItemClick` will treat it as a variable.

So in the above piece of code, when you do `onClick = {this.onNavBarItemClick()}`, the function is getting called there itself without the user clicking on it. Whereas if you do `onClick = {this.onNavBarItemCLick}` the function gets invoked only if you click on it.

You can also do `onClick = {()=>this.onNavBarItemClick()}`. By doing this you are creating an anonymous function and passing it to `onClick`.

So you can do either of `onClick = {this.onNavBarItemClick}` or `onClick = {()=> this.onNavBarItemClick()}`